# Vue and JQuery compatibility

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, vue.js

Are [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) and [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) 100% compatible?  How about [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) and [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/)?

I've been working with both for a while and I haven't had a problem with integration.  Can anyone demonstrate where there would be a problem?

Comment: Not 100%. There are problems with jquery cache. Somehow the $.data() function returns stale datas when the DOM changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Vue plays nice with jQuery.

The [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/examples/select2.html) includes integrating jQuery plugins as an example, in fact.

Comment: Thank you for that example.  I did know that Evan uses JQuery in the Vue docs here:  http://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Transitions however it's a perfect example of "do I need to make a directive every time I want to use a JQuery plugin, or else will stuff break?"  I would like to see some rules (if there are any) that govern JQuery/Vue compatibility

Comment: @user3089840 You'd want to use a directive when Vue should know about and/or manage the jQuery plugin or behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As @moh said, playing with the element order with Vue.js breaks some stuff for jQuery.

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/coelhoric/pen/rmqrdy). The idea of the demo is to reverse data to "reverse nodes" and use "data" jQuery's method.

After 2 reserves, the following code doesn't return the expected value.

```
$item.data('item')
```

For "c1" as $item, you'll get "c2".